# How to include font-awesome in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, css, codeigniter

i have include font-awesome but icons are show square box..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/font-awesome.css') ?>">
```

please help me

Comment: Can you use the cdn version?

Comment: check the file , ensure the file exist , and then check base_url , in config.php

Comment: cdn was worked but i want to use offline

Comment: this is my base url $config['base_url'] = '';

Comment: @Sibison , try like this : `$config['base_url'] = 'your domain /subfolder';` then in href : `<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/font-awesome.css` , then check your inspect element to see error in console

Comment: It is best to set your base_url in codeigniter 3 else css links may not work

Comment: Example `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/your_project/'`

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `base_url()` or `site_url()` for font-awesome.css only because of:

```css
@font-face {
font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.6.3');
  src: url('../font-awesome-4.6.3/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.6.3') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../font-awesome-4.6.3/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.6.3') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.6.3') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.6.3') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.6.3#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

**Solution 1.** If you don't want to download font-awesome, you can use:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />`

Of course this always works. Disanvantage of solution 1 is the dependence on the internet connection.

**Solution 2.** First of all, you must download all files of fontawesome(svg, woff, eot,...) and put them all in a folder - for example, let the name of the folder be `fontawesome`.

Then, you must remove the following code from the file `font-awesome.css`

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
      src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.6.3');
      src: url('../font-awesome-4.6.3/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.6.3') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../font-awesome-4.6.3/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.6.3') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.6.3') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.6.3') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.6.3#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
    }
```

After that, you copy them into the `<style></style>` of the `.html` or `.php` file, which you want to implement `font-awesome`. But you must change the `src` as follow:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
      src: url('<?=site_url('fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.6.3'); ?>');
      src: url('<?=site_url('fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.6.3') ; ?>') format('embedded-opentype'), url('<?=site_url('fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.6.3');?>') format('woff2'), url('<?=site_url('fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.6.3'); ?>') format('woff'), url('<?=site_url('fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.6.3'); ?>') format('truetype'), url('<?=site_url('fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.6.3#fontawesomeregular'); ?>') format('svg');
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
    }
```

and remember to add these in your `.html`, `.php` too:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=site_url("fontawesome/font-awesome.css"); ?>" />`

---

And including `glyphicon` of `bootstrap` is totally similar.

Comment: also      <?=site_url('  can use as    <?=base_url('assets/

Answer (score 0):

fontawesome is not only single css file it include more file internally so if you want to do it in offline you have to put all file related to font awesome like `fonts` or use online link is better option

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hosting on your server**

[Click here to Download Font-Awesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome-4.5.0.zip)

Extract the downloaded ZIP into your Codeigniter Directory. I assumed you have extracted FontAwesome in plugin/font-awesome/

Code to include the file in view:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('plugin/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'); ?>">
```

**Using CDN Hosted**

Simply Add this code into your view

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Comment: Yes. They have extracted incorrectly. As they are saying CDN is working fine but hosted is not working. But in last comment he said their `"$config['base_url'] = ''"` set to blank; so he to update the url here.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want the cdn then you can do this.

open the css file (in fontawesome/css) and change the url source of all font files.

this block

```
@font-face {


font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.6.3');
  src: url('../font-awesome-4.6.3/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.6.3') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../font-awesome-4.6.3/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.6.3') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.6.3') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.6.3') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.6.3#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

to

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('domainName/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.6.3');
  src: url('domainName/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.6.3') format('embedded-opentype'), url('domainName/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.6.3') format('woff2'), url('domainName/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.6.3') format('woff'), url('domainName/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.6.3') format('truetype'), url('http://localhost/khloe/assets/font-awesome-4.6.3/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.6.3#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not a difference, you are still able to use the following code:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

You can also include it via the CSS file by adding:

```
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/font-awesome.css">
```

and set your base_url in your config file like this

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://domain.com/websiteroot/';
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would recommend that you inspect your browser if there are any errors by pressing F12 on Chrome.

[image: Snapshot]

Make sure that the URL corresponds to the place you have put your font awesome folder: e.g.
Project
--Application
--Assets
----CSS
------font awesome
--------CSS
----------fontawesome.css
--system

If the path is correct then go to font awesome website to check the code of the icon you want, every icon you choose will have an example of how to use it.

https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery

Hope that helps